# How can I give index to users' events and preserve order with PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
+------------+------------------+--------------------+
|id.         |install_time_first|           timestamp|
+------------+------------------+--------------------+
|           2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-01 10:03:...|
|           3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:00:...|
|           2|        2022-02-02|                null|
|           3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-03 11:35:...|
|           1|        2022-02-01|                null|
|           2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-02 10:05:...|
|           3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:05:...|
|           4|        2022-02-02|                null|
|           1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:05:...|
|           2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-02 10:05:...|
|           4|        2022-02-02|2022-02-03 11:35:...|
|           1|        2022-02-01|                null|
|           1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:03:...|
|           1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:05:...|
|           4|        2022-02-02|2022-02-03 11:35:...|
|           2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-02 11:00:...|
|           4|        2022-02-02|2022-02-03 11:35:...|
|           3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-04 11:35:...|
|           1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:00:...|
+------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

And I want to sort the dataframe by `install_time_first` and add an index to each user (all his events) and preserve the order. For example:

```
+------------+------------------+--------------------+-----+
|id.         |install_time_first|           timestamp|index|
+------------+------------------+--------------------+-----+
|           1|        2022-02-01|                null|    1|
|           1|        2022-02-01|                null|    1|
|           1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:00:...|    1|
|           1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:03:...|    1|
|           1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:05:...|    1|
|           1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:05:...|    1|
|           3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:00:...|    2|
|           3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:05:...|    2|
|           3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-03 11:35:...|    2|
|           3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-04 11:35:...|    2|
|           2|        2022-02-02|                null|    3|
|           2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-01 10:03:...|    3|
|           2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-02 10:05:...|    3|
|           2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-02 10:05:...|    3|
|           2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-02 11:00:...|    3|
|           4|        2022-02-02|                null|    4|
|           4|        2022-02-02|2022-02-03 11:35:...|    4|
|           4|        2022-02-02|2022-02-03 11:35:...|    4|
|           4|        2022-02-02|2022-02-03 11:35:...|    4|
+------------+------------------+--------------------+-----+
```

How can I do that? I couldn't do it and keep it sorted

Answer (score 1):

Key observation here is that the "index" column has same "id" column values but ordered by "install_time_first", one way to look at this is to partition/orderBy on (install_time_first, id) and assign a unqiue index for each couple, I did 2 solution the first using joins and the second using windows with some tricks, I would prefer the first solution because the second one can be performance heavy:

**PS**: tou can delete this line of code in both solutions ".orderBy("install_time_first", "id")", I added it just to make sure the output is sorted so it can be readable:

**Prepare data:**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (2, "2022-02-02", "2022-02-01 10:03"),
    (3, "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01 10:00"),
    (2, "2022-02-02", None),
    (3, "2022-02-01", "2022-02-03 11:35"),
    (1, "2022-02-01", None),
    (2, "2022-02-02", "2022-02-02 10:05"),
    (3, "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01 10:05"),
    (4, "2022-02-02", None),
    (1, "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01 10:05"),
    (2, "2022-02-02", "2022-02-02 10:05"),
    (4, "2022-02-02", "2022-02-03 11:35"),
    (1, "2022-02-01", None),
    (1, "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01 10:03"),
    (1, "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01 10:05"),
    (4, "2022-02-02", "2022-02-03 11:35"),
    (2, "2022-02-02", "2022-02-02 11:00"),
    (4, "2022-02-02", "2022-02-03 11:35"),
    (3, "2022-02-01", "2022-02-04 11:35"),
    (1, "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01 10:00"),
], ("id", "install_time_first", "timestamp"))
```

**Solution 1:**

```
df_with_index = df.select("id", "install_time_first").distinct().orderBy("install_time_first", "id")\
    .withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id() + 1)\
    .withColumnRenamed("id", "id2").withColumnRenamed("install_time_first", "install_time_first2")
df.join(df_with_index, (df.id == df_with_index.id2) & (df.install_time_first == df_with_index.install_time_first2),
        "left").orderBy("install_time_first", "id").drop("id2", "install_time_first2").show()
```

**Solution 2:**

```
w = Window.partitionBy(col("id")).orderBy(col("install_time_first"))
w2 = Window.orderBy(col("install_time_first"))
df = df.withColumn("prev_id", lag("id", 1, None).over(w))
df.withColumn("index", when(df.prev_id.isNull() | (df.prev_id != df.id), 1).otherwise(0))\
    .withColumn("index", sum("index").over(w2.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)))\
    .orderBy("install_time_first", "id").drop("prev_id").show()
```

Both gives same results:

```
+---+------------------+----------------+-----+
| id|install_time_first|       timestamp|index|
+---+------------------+----------------+-----+
|  1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:05|    1|
|  1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:00|    1|
|  1|        2022-02-01|            null|    1|
|  1|        2022-02-01|            null|    1|
|  1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:03|    1|
|  1|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:05|    1|
|  3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-03 11:35|    2|
|  3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:00|    2|
|  3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-04 11:35|    2|
|  3|        2022-02-01|2022-02-01 10:05|    2|
|  2|        2022-02-02|            null|    3|
|  2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-02 10:05|    3|
|  2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-02 10:05|    3|
|  2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-02 11:00|    3|
|  2|        2022-02-02|2022-02-01 10:03|    3|
|  4|        2022-02-02|            null|    4|
|  4|        2022-02-02|2022-02-03 11:35|    4|
|  4|        2022-02-02|2022-02-03 11:35|    4|
|  4|        2022-02-02|2022-02-03 11:35|    4|
+---+------------------+----------------+-----+
```

Comment: _"Both gives same results:"_ is an under-statement since **Solution 1** moves all rows in a single partition (due to `monotonically_increasing_id()`) so you risk an OOM while the later window aggregation is distributing load across partitions. The later should only be considered a solution.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I didn't know monotonically_increasing_id moves all rows in a single partition, thanks, but isn't a window without .partitionBy ( second example ) do the same thing ?

Comment: Without `.partitionBy` they'd be equivalent. Glad you used `Window.partitionBy(col("id"))` since that's what keeps the query distributed.

Comment: But my second window doesn't use a partitionBy: w2 = Window.orderBy(col("install_time_first")), so both solution will move all data in a single partition

Comment: "I didn't know monotonically_increasing_id moves all rows in a single partition" i dont think it does it by itself but to make solution 1 working correctly you should move all data into one partition. The reason for this is that monotonically_increasing is guaranteed to be consecutive only within single partition, with many partitions you are going to have gaps in index. Other thing is that for some partition it may start from very weird number as it calculated based on partitionMask. I did quick check and for me first partitions start from 0 but second from 8589934592

Comment: @M_S I see thanks, I still think the first solution si better just because monotonically_increasing_id() is applied to a dataframe with .distinct(), judging from sample data in the question, I think this can reduce 4x to5x the amount of rows.